# How can I bind "modifier + arrow" keys to home/end/pageup/pagedown under X?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap, xdotool, sxhkd

I have a new 60% keyboard (NuPhy Air60), but it does not have any way to trigger pageup/pagedown or home/end keys.

My goal is to recover these commands with a custom keybinding, using a modifier key like `hyper` or `alt`, in combination with the arrow keys. For my preference, something like:

- alt + arrowup = pageup
- alt + arrowdown = pagedown
- alt + arrowleft = home
- alt + arrowright = end

I tried to use `xmodmap` to make the bindings -- but unfortunately due to a years-old known chromium bug, my bindings there did not work in Chrome or VSCode.

What else can be done?

Comment: Can you please link to the chromium bug?

Comment: @MiniGod it's [this chromium bug, #394552](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=394552#c18)

Answer (score 0):

#### Keybindings via `sxhkd` and `xdotool`

These programs can be used as an alternative to xmodmap to facilitate custom key binds, and in a way that circumvents the issue with chromium.

- `sxhkd` is a program that can be configured to run commands in response to key combinations.
- `xdotool` is a program that can emulate keyboard events, targeted at the currently-focused application.

To bind `alt+arrowkeys` to `home/end/pageup/pagedown`:

1. Install `sxhkd` and `xdotool`

   - for arch linux: `sudo pacman -S sxhkd xdotool`
   - these packages are commonly available in other distro's package managers
2. Configure sxhkd in `~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc` as follows:

   ```
   alt + Up
     xdotool keyup Up key --clearmodifiers Prior

   alt + Down
     xdotool keyup Down key --clearmodifiers Next

   alt + Left
     xdotool keyup Left key --clearmodifiers Home

   alt + Right
     xdotool keyup Right key --clearmodifiers End
   ```

   - note that `Prior` and `Next` are "keysym" names that correspond to pageup and pagedown.
3. Run the sxhkd daemon: `sxhkd`

   - you probably want to run this at startup
   - instructions for that will vary based on your specific desktop environment or window manager.

Source: this particular blog post was very helpful [Using Capslock + hjkl as arrow keys on Linux](https://tbuss.de/posts/2021/5-capslock_as_vim_modifier/)